# How to overwrite url title with a custom text in InAppWebView with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

For my project I use InAppWebView to launch some links in a Web View in Flutter. Is it possible to set a custom text instead of the website url in the top bar? For example, instead of stackoverflow.com I would like to have "Welcome to Stackoverflow".

[image]

```
ChromeSafariBrowser().open(
     url: Uri.parse('https://stackoverflow.com/'),
     options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
       ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true),
     ),
   );
```